# setInterval start and stop behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'm creating a stopwatch that has a button to start and stop the time, but I'm having trouble with setInterval behavior.

When declared in React's functional component level, it will run once it's mounted.
Example:

```
const Timer = () => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)
}
```

When I declare it inside a function, it will not run until the function is called but then I can't get it to stop.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [start, setStart] = useState(false)

    const startStopTimer = () => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)
    }

    return (<Button 
                onClick={() => {
                   setStarted(!start)
                   startStopTimer()
                }
             > Start/Stop </Button>)
}
```

I've then tried adding `clearInterval()` in the function and calling it conditionally if `start === false`. In this implementation, the first button click does nothing. Second click starts the timer, but it can't be stopped.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [start, setStart] = useState(false)

    const startStopTimer = () => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)
        if (!started) clearInterval(timer)
    }

    return (<Button 
                onClick={() => {
                   setStarted(!start)
                   startStopTimer()
                }
             > Start/Stop </Button>)
}
```

Comment: because you keep creating the variable timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, I suggest you to modify your code like this:

```
const Timer = () => {
    //const [start, setStart] = useState(false) do not use state for scripting reasons
    let timer = null;

    const startStopTimer = () => {
        if(!timer) timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)
        else {
           clearInterval(timer)
           timer = null
        } 
    }

    return (<Button 
                onClick={() => {
                   //setStarted(!start)
                   startStopTimer()
                }
             > Start/Stop </Button>)
}
```

Explanation: `timer` should be defined outside the `startStopTimer` otherwise, every time you launch `startStopTimer`, you create a new `timer`.

Ok this was easy, but now the important part: I strongly suggest you to not use react state for scripting reason. react state should be used only for rendering reasons. Why? Because hook are async and if you read `start` immediately after use `setStart`, you will read an old value.

Comment: I just tried this method and it works for starting the timer. It does not stop however. On every click, it adds another instance of `setInterval`. For example, first click results in console.log('running') once every second. Second click logs "running" twice every second and so on.

Comment: Sorry @SimonWong I forgot to put `timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)`... Try now. Should work.

Comment: Thanks! But now once it stops, it won't start again. I added `timer = null` in the else statement and it works perfectly now! Please edit your answer to include that :)

Comment: I was just reminded why I need to use `useState`. I would like to update the UI with the new value every time `setInterval` is called. But like you said, it's calling setInterval multiple times if I use `let [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)` and click the button multiple times. Any idea how I should approach this?

Comment: @SimonWong But you need just to visualize on UI if setInterval is called, correct? I mean you want to see 1 or 0 in UI

Comment: I created another post to not deviate from the original question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458425/setinterval-react-hooks-causing-multiple-updates

Answer (score 0):

`timer` variable is local and only scoped inside `sartStopTimer()` every time you call `sartStopTimer()` it generates new `timer` and when clearing timeout you are only clearing the recently generated one not previous `timer`

```
let timer;
const startStopTimer = () => {
        timer = setInterval(() => console.log('running'), 1000)
        if (!started) clearInterval(timer)
    }
```

Made `timer` global variable.

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [timerId, setTimerId] = useState(null)
        
    function startStopTimer(){
      if (timerId) {
        clearInterval(timerId)
        setTimerId(null)
      } else {
        setTimerId(setInterval(() => console.log('hello'), 1000))
      }
    }
    return <button onClick={startStopTimer}> Start/Stop </button>
}
```

There is no need to use state, by the way. In case you do not need to keep the timer state you can definitely use plain variable, of course.