# setInterval + React hooks causing multiple updates within component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I'm building a stopwatch UI that shows the time in seconds. With the click of a button, the timer will start counting upwards and stop when it is clicked again. User should be able to start it again.

The issue I'm having is that I can have `setInterval` working correctly but once I include `setTime` hook, the component updates to render the time in the UI but the `setInterval` instance is being called multiple times. This leads to odd rendering behavior.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0)
    let timer

    const startStopTimer = () => {
        if (!timer) timer = setInterval(() => setTime(time++), 1000)
        else {
           clearInterval(timer)
           timer = null
        }
    }

    return (
            <div>
               <p>Time: {time} seconds</p>
               <Button 
                   onClick={() => {
                      startStopTimer()
                   }
               > Start/Stop </Button>
            </div>
           )
}
```

Example behavior would be:

1. User clicks Start/Stop
2. Timer starts from 0 and counts upward
3. User clicks Start/Stop
4. Timer stops immediately
5. User clicks Start/Stop
6. Timer continues where it left off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example of stale closure in React hooks, inside your setInterval value of `time` is not changing after calling `setTime`. Change your code with:

`setInterval(() => setTime(currentTime => currentTime + 1), 1000)`.

`setTime` just like the `setState` of classful components also accepts a callback function which has the current value as the first param

Also, the `timer` variable is useless in you code since on every re-render it will be undefined and you wont't have the access of return value of `setInterval`, so it will reinitialize the `setInterval`. To handle that use `useRef`, you can store the return of `setInterval` in `.current`, which will be available to you after subsequent  re renders so no more re-init of setInterval and you can also use `clearInterval`

Solution:

```js
const {useState, useRef} = React;
const {render} = ReactDOM;

const Timer = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const timer = useRef(null);
  const startStopTimer = () => {
    if (!timer.current) {
      timer.current = setInterval(() => setTime(currentTime => currentTime + 1), 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
      timer.current = null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Time: {time} seconds</p>
      <button
        onClick={startStopTimer}
      >
        Start/Stop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This resulted in the original issue of multiple updates. On every button click, the `time` goes up faster and faster. Starting from 1 every second, goes to 2 every second, to 3 and on.

Comment: It is because to clear the timer you need to store the value in such a way that after every re render you can have access to the timer variable of your `setInterval`, for that use `useRef`

Comment: Yes, useRef was the solution. Thank you!! Btw, the code snippet has an error but I've got it working on my end.

Comment: There is no reason to use `useRef` to save state. Why not use `const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)`? Then use `timer` to check for an active timer and `setTimer` to clear/set a new timer if needed.

Comment: I would say `useRef` is the best fit as it does not rerenders. when you have `const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null)`, it will re-render the component when timer value is changed, that is fine when you start the timer because the component is going to rerender because of `setTime` but when you stop the timer and set timer to `null`, you don't really need your component to re-render, so why not use `useRef`? @3limin4t0r

Comment: @Ashish I was thinking because the documentation clearly states: [Don’t Overuse Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs). One additional render on such a small component is not that big of a deal. You could also use the additional render as an opportunity to swap between different scenarios. For example use `timer ? 'stop' : 'start'` instead of a general `start/stop` text. Or use it to split up `startStopTimer` into two separate events, then assign the one needed. `onClick={timer ? stopTimer : startTimer}`

Comment: 'Don’t Overuse Refs' is for the ref attribute and not useRef method.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

 The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class. @3limin4t0r

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a react class component. This example keeps track of the start time instead of adding to some value on a certain interval. Then when you stop the timer it accumulates the passed time.

The callback passed to `setInterval` might not always exactly be called each `n` ms. If the JavaScript engine is busy it might take a few ms longer. Keeping a counter would slowly offset the actual passed time the longer it runs.

```js
const {Component} = React;
const {render} = ReactDOM;

class StopWatch extends Component {
  state = {startTime: null, accTime: 0, intervalId: null};
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
  }
  
  ms() {
    const {startTime, accTime} = this.state;
    if (!startTime) return accTime;
    return Date.now() - startTime + accTime;
  }
  
  start = () => {
    this.setState({
      startTime: Date.now(),
      intervalId: setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(), 10)
    });
  }
  
  stop = () => {
    clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    this.setState({
      startTime: null,
      accTime: this.ms(),
      intervalId: null
    });
  }
  
  reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      accTime: 0,
      startTime: this.state.startTime && Date.now()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.ms() / 1000}</h1>
        {this.state.startTime
          ? <button onClick={this.stop}>stop</button>
          : <button onClick={this.start}>start</button>}
        <button onClick={this.reset}>reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<StopWatch />, document.getElementById("stop-watch"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="stop-watch"></div>
```